# Audio file not working on page load

Tags: javascript, loops, audio

```
document.getElementById('audio_1').addEventListener('ended', function() {
    this.play();
    this.currentTime = 0;

}, false);
```

In this music does not start on page load, it repeats n number of times, once started..but not once page load

Answer (score 1):

You never start the playback. You need to call `.play()` onload or use the `autoplay` attribute in your `<audio>` tag.

Oh, and you can achieve looping much easier without any JavaScript. Simply use the `loop` attribute in your `<audio>` tag.