# audio play() not working on page load when tab is in the background

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, audio, html5-audio, dom-events

here's the issue I'm currently facing:

Suppose that I am on my website's home page. I use the right mouse click and select **"Open url to a new tab"** without switching to that tab. I want a sound to play without having to bring that tab to the foreground.

Is there a way to do so? Currently, sound plays only when tab comes to the foreground.I am using Chrome 69 and Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

I have seen similar questions to the forum (such as [question1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14070453/audio-file-not-working-on-page-load) and [question2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38269953/safari-html5-audio-wont-play-when-tab-is-in-the-background) ) but couldn't find an answer for my case.

Sample of code can be seen below:

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        $('body').append(
            '<audio id="test_audio">' +
                '<source src="/sounds/bip.wav" type="audio/wav" >' +
            '</audio>'
        );

        function play_test_sound() {
            var testAudio = document.getElementById('test_audio');
            var testPlayPromise = testAudio.play();
            var testPlayButtonMessage = document.querySelector('#test_audio_message');
            var testPlayButton = document.querySelector('#test_play');

            if (testPlayPromise !== undefined) {
                testPlayPromise.then(function() {
                     testPlayButtonMessage.hidden = true;
                }).catch(function(error) {
                    testPlayButton.addEventListener('click', function(){
                       play_test_sound();
                    });
                    testPlayButtonMessage.hidden = false;
                });
            }
        }

        play_test_sound();
    }
</script>

<div class="m-a-md row" id="test_audio_message" hidden>
    <div class="col-md-8">Click <a id="test_play">here</a> to enable sound.</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Did you checked your console? No message like *the call to play has been denied because no user-gesture?*

Comment: There is no error to the console. As mentioned to my post, as soon as the tab comes to the foreground, audio plays. Added console logs inside `testPlayPromise.then` and `catch` and promise is successful (goes to `then`). The problem is when tab is opened through right mouse click, and never comes to the foreground.